# Equidistribuion of distances of integer points to a circle

Tags: real-analysis, probability, geometric-probability

I have noticed in the following graph that the  distance
between points $k \in\mathbb{Z}^2\cap C_7^1$ ($C_7^1$:=Circle with radius 7 and shell with thickness 1) and the nearest point on the inner circle is quite random.
[image]

I did some further investigations in R and figured out that the distances for large radii are seemingly uniformly distributed.

[image]

This leads to the following question. Let $C_r^1$ be the centered circle with radius r and shell with thickness 1. We denote by $A_r$ the set $C_r^1 \cap \mathbb{Z}^2$.

We replace each element in the set $A_r$ with the corresponding distance to the nearest point on the centered circle with radius r.

Now i want to proof that for every subinterval $[a,b]$ in $[0,1]$ we have

$$
\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\text{card}(A_r\cap [a,b])}{\text{card}(A_r)}=b-a.
$$

Does anyone have an idea how to do this proof?

Comment: Assuming that the points are uniformly distributed within the intersection of circles of radius  $7$ and $8$, there should be more points towards the outer circle , since there is more area where points can be. Thus, the distances will not have a uniform distribution, since there will be a skew towards larger distances.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I did some further investigations and i could not find a "skew" effect.

Comment: @Bergson: Since the thickness of the shell is fixed at $1$ while the radius goes to $\infty$, the difference in densities decreases with $\frac1r$ and doesn't survive the limit being considered here.

Comment: Are you aware of the [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem#Bounds_on_a_solution_and_conjecture)? I don't know whether the existing bounds for that decide your question either way, but it would certainly make sense to look at the methods used to derive them.